# Dynamically building RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have a non-fixed List of *.Rmd files and want to dynamically render them into a single html File with RMarkdown.

Like this:

```
reportFiles <- list()
reportFiles[[1]] <- "F:\\report1.Rmd"
reportFiles[[2]] <- "F:\\report2.Rmd"
outputPath <- "F:\\report.html"
rmarkdown::render(input = reportFiles, output_file = outputPath)
```

But that doesnt work and i couldnt find a solution on how to do something like this. In all scenarios it either creates multiple files or you have to know what files yuo want to render beforehand or you have to create a temporary *.Rmd file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One can combine multiple Rmd files into a single output document by modifying the code posted with the question.

First, the documents must be combined into a single Rmd before processing with `rmarkdown::render()`.  Second, all files combined must take account of the following constraints.

1. Only the first Rmd file can contain document header information
2. Section labels must be unique across all Rmd files combined into a single Rmd for rendering.

The general approach is to read the files into a character vector, write the vector to a temporary Rmd file, then render the combined document.

```
library(rmarkdown)

# list of files to be combined
reports <- c("report1.Rmd","report2.Rmd")

# read the files & combine into a single character vector
theReports <- unlist(lapply(reports,readLines))

# use writeLines() to combine into single Rmd
tmpFile <- writeLines(theReports,"tmpReport.Rmd")

# render the combined document 
render(input = "tmpReport.Rmd")
```

When rendered to an HTML document, the output looks like this:

[image]

### Additional Considerations

We used a character vector instead of a `list()` to store the file names because the additional complexity of a `list()` was not needed to drive `lapply()` in this situation.

Use of a character vector allows the solution to be modified to potentially retrieve a list of files from a subdirectory with `list.files()`, as in:

```
 reports <- list.files(path="./myReportDir/",
                       pattern="report[[:digit:]]+.Rmd",full.names=TRUE)
```

Also, one can segregate the header information into a file that contains only header info, such as `report_header.Rmd`.

Next, in order to automate retrieval of the files from a directory, one must ensure that the sort order of the file names matches the intended order of inclusion in the output document. H/T to Petr Kajzar for the regular expression to extract only files with a numbered report name from `list.files()`.

Finally, also as suggested by Petr Kajzar in the comments, one can use a truly temporary file  to drive `rmarkdown::render()` as follows.

```
tmpfile <- tempfile(fileext=".Rmd")
writeLines(theReports,tmpfile)
render(input = tmpfile)
```

### Appendix

To make the example completely reproducible, we include the text of `report1.Rmd` and `report2.Rmd`. These files must be copied & saved to a local computer in order for the script above to read, write, and render them.

#### report1.Rmd

````
---
title: "report 1"
author: "lg"
date: "7/6/2020"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

## R Markdown

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

When you click the **Knit** button a document will be generated that includes both content as well as the output of any embedded R code chunks within the document. You can embed an R code chunk like this:

```{r cars}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

#### report2.Rmd

Notice that the content in the second report conforms to the two constraints listed above.

````
## Report number 2

This is some text for the second markdown document. Considerations to make concatenation of multiple Rmd files into a single output document work:

1. Files 2 thru N must not have Rmd header information
2. Files that are combined into a single Rmd must not have duplicate section labels


```{r cars2}
summary(cars)
```

## Including Plots

You can also embed plots, for example:

```{r pressure2, echo=FALSE}
plot(pressure)
```

Note that the `echo = FALSE` parameter was added to the code chunk to prevent printing of the R code that generated the plot.
````

Comment: Good approach! You can even list files with `reportFiles <- list.files(pattern = "report[[:digit:]]+.Rmd")`, then read the lines and save them into real temporary file like `tmpFile <- tempfile(fileext = ".Rmd")` and then `writeLines(theReports, tmpFile)` and finally `rmarkdown::render(tmpFile)`.

Comment: @PetrKajzar - funny you should say that, as I was adding `list.files()` to an "additional considerations" section as you posted the comment. I especially appreciate your comments about the right pattern to use in `list.files()` because I don't use regular expressions enough to write the code without looking things up.

Comment: Nice. :-) I had almost the same solution as you, but you were faster and your answer is really cool with details like screeshots and sample data, so I didn't post mine at all and leaved only a quick comment with some thoughts. :-)

Comment: @PetrKajzar -  I prefer to post tutorial style answers, and by using the sample Rmd that is generated by RStudio as the baseline for the two reports I could quickly debug the process. For example, as I was testing the solution I discovered that I had to remove the header info from `report2.Rmd` as well as change the names of the section labels to make them unique. I post an answer once I have a basic solution working, then I refine the answer with subsequent edits.